# How to fill this textbox?

Tags: javascript

I'm encountering a problem when I am trying to fill in this textbox.
It just doesn't works.

This is the code of the textbox:

```
<div id="input-field" class="input-field editable" type="text" contenteditable="true" data-ph="Type here to send a message" g_editable="true" role="textbox" style="display: inline-block; border: none; height: 2.7375em; padding: 0.3em 0.3em 0.3em 0.6em; width: 1007px; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; font-family: 'Comic Sans', 'Comic Sans MS', sans-serif; font-size: 200%;"></div>
```

And this is what I have tried:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("input-field")[0].value = 'lmao';
```

Comment: `.value` is for form inputs. You probably want `.innerHTML` for an editable div.

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName("input-field")[0].innerHTML = 'lmao'; Does not work either.

Comment: @NotAGoodCoder https://jsfiddle.net/1s53Lgto/

Comment: That is weird. I am pasting it into Chrome console on the webpage, but it says: Cannot set property 'textContent' of undefined